# Making sum in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm new to the forum and hope to help and learn a lot with you.

i have a problem and tried to solve it but i could not solve it by myself, could give me a hand?

i have this code:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; allowed
var moreprod         = $(".contenedor"); wrapper
var add_button      = $("#e");

var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
        x++; //text box increment
        $(moreprod).append('<div class="fieldprod"><div id="a"><input type="text" placeholder="Product"></input></div><div id="b" class="csymbol" data-symbol="$"><input id="prices" type="text" placeholder=" 0.00"></input></div><div id="c"><input id="prices" type="text" placeholder="qty"></input></div><div id="d" class="csymbol" data-symbol="$"><p id="qty">0.00</p></div><div id="f" class="removebtn">-</div></div>'); //add input box
    }
});


$(moreprod).on("click",".removebtn", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="result">total</div>
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="fieldprod">
<div id="a">
<input type="text" placeholder="Product"></input>
</div>
<div id="b" class="csymbol" data-symbol="$">
<input id="prices" type="text" placeholder=" 0.00"></input>
</div>
<div id="c">
<input id="prices" type="text" placeholder="qty"></input>
</div>
<div id="d" class="csymbol" data-symbol="$"><p id="qty">0.00</p></div>
<div id="e">+</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and i'm dynamically creating three input and two divs which together form a row, but you can create more rows, i'm trying to do a sum of the values of two input (c = a + b) in a row.

[image: pic 1]

but if i add a new row then make the sum of the values (g = e + f) and then do this sum (total = c + g).

[image: see this picture]

any help?

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :S

Comment: r u getting any errors or something?

Comment: no any error, watch it: http://jsfiddle.net/markusfenix/jovx3hoo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are replicating `id` which should be unique in the document. Better use classes.
2. You need to capture the `change` event of the `input` element and do your calculations there.

The script to handle it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10;
    var moreprod = $(".contenedor");
    var add_button = $("#e");
    var grandTotal = $('#grand-total');

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++; //text box increment
            $(moreprod).append('<div class="fieldprod"><div><input type="text" placeholder="Product"></input></div><div class="csymbol" data-symbol="$"><input class="price" type="text" placeholder=" 0.00"></input></div><div><input class="quantity" type="text" placeholder="qty"></input></div><div class="csymbol" data-symbol="$"><p class="product-total">0.00</p></div><div class="removebtn">-</div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });


    moreprod.on("click", ".removebtn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.fieldprod').remove();
        x--;
        moreprod.find('.price').first().trigger('change');
    }).on('change', '.price, .quantity', function(){
        var group = $(this).closest('.fieldprod'),
            quantity = +group.find('.quantity').val(),
            price = +group.find('.price').val(),
            total = group.find('.product-total');

        total.text( (quantity*price).toFixed(2) );

        var grand = moreprod
                        .find('.product-total').get()
                        .reduce(function(p,v){
                            return p + +$(v).text();
                        },0);
        grandTotal.text(grand.toFixed(2));

    });

});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9tp5aycy/

Comment: thanks!!! works perfect and now i can see all my mistakes, i can't vote for your answer yet, but thank you so much!!!

Comment: hi mr. petrioli, i hope you'r well, i was playing with your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markusfenix/v9n11nz7/) and i have a question, is there any way to save the value of the inputs in a localstorage file and have the option to load them later?

Comment: Not in a local file (*since browser javascript does not have access to file i/o operations*). If you mean the localStorage that is supplied by the browser then yes. See http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

You want to dynamically add and remove rows with products (in a shop software).

BUT, you are reusing the SAME id values, which is bad.
Ids must be globally unique.

There are many options to archieve your goal:

1. make all id unique, use x1, x2, x3 ...
2. remove all ids and only use CSS selectors to get the fields http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
3. ...

Another issue is the remove button. I cannot believe that it works.
I would register the remove handler just after I would append the row.
At the moment there is only one remove handler registered, so the only one which should be deletable is the first row.

Comment: hi Ix42.de because i'm new i could not include the link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markusfenix/jovx3hoo/ all (in my eye) works well